# Why is this not a good question?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [I don't know how I ended up here but what is ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108791/i-dont-know-how-i-ended-up-here-but-what-is-ubuntu)

Why is this not a good question?

---

Update: here is the deleted post for those who can't see it:

[image]

Comment: I assume you infer that from the downvotes. Just for the record: It’s not you that gets hate, it’s the question! A downvote means the voter found your question “unclear or not useful” or that it “does not show any research effort” in their eyes. Don’t take it personally, rather take the [tour], read [ask] and improve your question. Getting a single upvote on a question makes up for two and a half downvotes you received.

Comment: Could someone who can see deleted posts share a screenshot instead of the (now) dead link to the Q?

Comment: @guntbert https://imgur.com/a/h6euoOy

Comment: I think you should improve your question and ask it again, linking it here as well. Because the duplicate does not really answer your question. Ubuntu is an operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you genuinely want an answer to your question. So here are a few things that could be improved

- Your title mentions: 'I don't know how I ended up here' which is completely irrelevant to the question
- You then continue to call your own question stupid. I know that's not what you mean, but essentially you should ask the question, not reflect on it.
- Your real question is: What is ubuntu and what can you do with it. Here you could improve the question by making it more specific: Is it a video-editing tool? Does it replace windows? Do you use it together with windows? Is it targetted at specialised people? Programmers? Whatever you think of you could add here.
- You then add a link to google, but you don't mention what you learned from that query. What are the results telling you?

All the above make your question look sloppy and make it look like you have not taken the effort to research your question. Next time try to be specific, clear, without too much meta. There are many professionals on this site and they don't want to waste their time. So the more specific, the better.

Answer (score 11):

You're just new here and this is not a forum which most users are familiar with: this is a Question & Answer site and as a picture says more than a 1000 words:

[image: Stack Exchange Venn Diagram]

We're like the little asterisk in the middle, so [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and then [read the help pages](https://askubuntu.com/help) because we like to have well-defined questions that lead to well-defined answers *without opinions, just facts* so they lead to specific solutions to specific problems that help you now, ***and** everyone else that has the same kind of problem in the future!*

More specifically, [here is a list of the best questions on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=votes), so have a look at those as well and try to imitate them *and you will post **great** questions!*

### :-)

Comment: Forum/Wiki is OK but I'm not sure about the other 2...

Comment: Wiki/Blog/Reddit mostly and forum only in the comments.  **;-)** @Zhigalin

Comment: You could also think of successful questions as recent questions that were actually answered and accepted. The highest rep questions are sometimes confusing because they deal with larger topics that are relevant to many people.